# ASP.net: How does this OnClick function work with those symbols: $ and #

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor-pages

```
onClick=" $('#AutoCloseWindow').val('true'); $('#idForm').submit();
```

I am trying to make sense of the $ and # symbols. I was expecting to find a function called "AutoCloseWindow" but with no luck- I am guessing this has something to do with the $ and # symbols. Can someone clarify these to me?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I found this later in the cshtml (RAZOR) page:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveIndex")" method="POST" id="idForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item.Id)
```

This seems to be a form accepting what the button sent out. HOwever, there doesnt seem to be any code executed in the following  tag, all I see is html elements underneath.

Comment: It's jQuery code, the $ indicates a jquery command, and the # is the ID selector in a CSS selector. So in other words this is client-side code to run in the browser, and not really anything to do with asp.net directly. It sets the value of some form element (whose ID is "AutoCloseWindow") to "true" and then submits a form (whose ID is "idForm"). https://jquery.com/, https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/, https://api.jquery.com/val/, https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand. However, how do I find the underlying function that is triggered when this button is clicked?

Comment: What do you mean? The code you've shown _is_ the code which is triggered when the button is clicked - at least in terms of the client-side anyway. Are you asking how to understand which asp.net code is executed? It would be whatever code handles the form which is submitted. There are many varieties of asp.net so giving any more details of what to look for would depend on which type of asp.net application you have (e.g. webforms, mvc, razor pages, blazor etc)

Comment: All I know is that this is a razor page. I upate my question with something else...

Comment: Ok. It will execute whatever code is associated with the "SaveIndex" action in the asp.net code (this is denoted by `@Url.Action("SaveIndex")` in the form's "action" attribute).

Comment: I actually managed to find a function called "SaveIndex" in a (imo) completely random class that is fired after the save button is clicked. I think I can handle this from here on, as this is now just c#., Thank you my friend!

Comment: As I understand Razor pages (I haven't really used them myself) probably it goes through an  OnPostAsync method in a page file first, which initially handles the POST request from the form, and then that might call the method you've found. Maybe having a look at the raw generated source code of your form (via the browser's developer tools) to see what URL the URL.Action method actually generated might help give a clue about that, potentially.